# Jordan canonical forms determined by a minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Find the Jordan canonical forms of all $9\times 9$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ with minimal polynomial $x^2(x-3)^3$.

My method: each factor of the minimal polynomial corresponds to a type of Jordan blocks with their maximal orders equal to the multiplicity of the factor. Hence all possible Jordan blocks are (List A)

\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}

Hence all possible matrices are

\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & &&&&&& \\ 0 & 0 &&&&&&&\\&&3 & 1 & 0 &&&&\\ &&0 & 3 & 1 &&&&\\&&0 & 0 & 3  &&&&\\ &&&&&B&&&\end{bmatrix}

where $B$ are $4\times 4$ matrices chosen arbitrarily as a combination of all possible blocks listed in List A:

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &0&&\\&&0&\\&&&0\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &0&&\\&&0&\\&&&3\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &0&&\\&&3&\\&&&3\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &3&&\\&&3&\\&&&3\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3 &&& \\ &3&&\\&&3&\\&&&3\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &3 & 1 & 0 \\ &0 & 3 & 1 \\&0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3&&& \\ &3 & 1 & 0 \\ &0 & 3 & 1 \\&0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &0 &  \\& &  &0  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &0 &  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &3 &  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &3 & 1  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &3 & 1  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &&& \\ &3 &  &  \\ & &3 & 1  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3 &&& \\ &3 &  &  \\ & &3 & 1  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 3 &1&& \\ &3 &  &  \\ & &3 & 1  \\& &  &3  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&& \\ &0 &  &  \\ & &0 & 1  \\& &  &0  \end{bmatrix}.

However, some classmates said I need to consider the primary factor and invariant factor thus cut off some of the possibilities. I am quite confused...

Comment: Can you do a favor... please write that matrices side by side.. it would be easy to check if any thing is missing every time we have to scroll down to check if you have written some particular case or something like that..

Comment: It looks alright to me. Each of the above forms have $x^2(x-3)^3$ as the minimal polynomial and therefore can't be excluded.

Comment: Your approach is sound and I did not see an error. But note that depending on your definition of Jordan form you might want to reorder the Jordan blocks in each matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct except that without a convention about how blocks are ordered, you need to count permutations of blocks for each of your sixteen matrices. I count 892.  Following is my work where each row in the table represents one of your matrices, and the number under a block is the frequency of that block in the matrix.
\begin{array}{cccccrl}
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 3 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} & \mbox{permutations} \\ \hline
1 & 1 &   &   & 4 & 6!/4!    =  30 \\
1 & 1 &   & 1 & 3 & 6!/3!    = 120 \\
1 & 1 &   & 2 & 2 & 6!/2!/2! = 180 \\
1 & 1 &   & 3 & 1 & 6!/3!    = 120 \\
1 & 1 &   & 4 &   & 6!/4!    =  30 \\
2 & 1 &   &   & 1 & 4!/2!    =  12 \\
2 & 1 &   & 1 &   & 4!/2!    =  12 \\
1 & 2 &   &   & 2 & 5!/2!/2! =  30 \\
1 & 2 &   & 1 & 1 & 5!/2!    =  60 \\
1 & 2 &   & 2 &   & 5!/2!/2! =  30 \\
1 & 2 & 1 &   &   & 4!/2!    =  12 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &   & 2 & 5!/2!    =  60 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5!       = 120 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 &   & 5!/2!    =  60 \\
1 & 1 & 2 &   &   & 4!/2!    =  12 \\
1 & 3 &   &   &   & 4!/3!    =   4 \\ \hline
  &   &   &   &   &            892 & \mbox{total}
\end{array}